# Jenkins windows batch command starts before earlier windows batch command completed

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

In Jenkins: I'm having a windows batch command which runs:

```
wmic /node:[server name] process call create  "cmd.exe /c [bat file]".
```

The problem is that the coming step in the jenkins project (also windows batch command) runs before the batch tasks (restore DB etc.) complete.
I would like to know how can make the first windows batch command wait until completed, so that the second step won't run yet.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is the window command processor and you start a __separate__ command process to process a batch file as parallel task. So the behavior is exactly as defined by you. Is it not possible to simple __call__ the batch file using command __CALL__? I mean simply using `call "Name of other batch file"` instead of the entire line you use here.

Comment: Mofi, thanks for the rapid response. I realized that the wmic actually "response" for creating the cmd.exe and this is its indication for success\failure. Youre proposal is logic, but all I found for executing a batch file with wmic include creating a cmd.exe process. I actually need to run the batch file without a "mediator", but directly. Maybe wmic is not the right approache.

Comment: Another option is to install Jenkins slave on the remote server, create a seperate project for executing the batch file(run it locally), and locate it as a preceding project for the later steps. I assume it should work, but I prefered avoiding it